# Route53 setup domain is redirecting to S3 address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I am trying to host my static website on S3 over https. I followed this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DiIaoIcoKNY&t=620s)

- I created S3 bucket with all default settings
- Created cloudFront distribution, added a certificate, set and did everything in the guide.
- Added a record set in Route53 and created a subdomain

now whenever I try to access the subdomain I created, it redirects me to origin domain name which is an S3 bucket.

For example if I had this domain: https://site.domain.com and by bucket is site-cloudfront and by origin domain name is site-cloudfront.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/index.html

It's going to redirect me to origin domain name from the one I want to access. Which is incorrect. How to fix this? what setting should be wrong here?

Comment: Hi, can you confirm the following settings? Distribution additionals names, and the origin name? Just say whats where.

Comment: There's no field as distribution additionals or origin names in Cloud front settings.

Comment: From the CloudFront distribution look for "Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs)", then look at "Origins and Origin Groups" tab and get the value of "Origin Domain and Path"

Comment: in alternate domain name I added full subdomain like: al-ahli-appointment.droobihealth.net and in origin domain name and path it's al-ahli-appointment-cloudfront.s3.amazonaws.com
and it's redirecting to later

Comment: What does running a DIG command do against your subdomain? Accessing it in your browser can you see the redirect and the path it follows?

Comment: This issue has now fixed itself, hasn't it?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yes, I just changed copied S3 bucket full address and pasted in origin name and enabled static web hosting in S3. That fixed it.

Comment: *"Fixed itself"* implies an issue that resolves itself without intervention... and that is what likely would have happened eventually because CloudFront uses a legacy feature of S3 to find the bucket region when you don't specify it, and this feature doesn't work immediately after bucket creation except when the bucket is in us-east-1.